# Aligning objects to bottom of sizers in wxPython

Tags: python, wxwidgets, wxpython

I've been trying to add a button to the bottom of a sizer for a while and cant seem to get it to work right. Ive provided the code from my design along with a badly designed ascii layout. I want the back button to be in the bottom left corner of my frame.

```
    ---------------------------------
    |          TITLE                 |
    |                                |
    |                                |
    |                                |
    |   BUTTON1           BUTTON2    |
    |                                |
    |                                |
    |                                |
    |                                |
    |                                |
    |                                |
    | BACK BUTTON                    |
    ---------------------------------
```

CODE:

```
    Title = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Title", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
    Title.SetMinSize((100, 100))
    Title.SetFont(wx.Font(20, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, ""))

    self.Button1 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Button 1")
    self.Button2 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Button 2")
    self.BackButton = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Back")

    SplitSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    ButtonSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    SplitSizer.Add(Title, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)
    ButtonSizer.Add(self.Button1, 0, 0, 0)
    ButtonSizer.Add(self.Button2, 0, 0, 0)
    SplitSizer.Add(ButtonSizer, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
    SplitSizer.Add(self.BackButton, 0, wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM | wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL, 0)

    self.SetSizer(SplitSizer)
```

Edit: 
I set the frame such that the window cant be resized. A screenshot of the output looks like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIQ1m.jpg

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what it looks like when you execute this code?

Comment: All your items in the sizers don't change its size, except the area for the pair of buttons, This area will grow horizontally, but not the buttons it contains. The BackButton should stay always size-unchanged at bottom-left corner. Apart from what Igor asked you, please edit the question and explain the desired behaviour when the window is resized.

Comment: Place `SplitSizer.AddStretchSpacer()` just before adding the back button to the sizer

Answer (score 4):

Aligning items in box sizers only works in the direction transversal to the sizer primary direction. So using `ALIGN_BOTTOM` in a `VERTICAL` sizer `SplitSizer` doesn't make sense (and in wxWidgets 3.1+ you will get an assertion failure explaining this to you).

Instead, you need to push the button to the bottom by adding a stretchable item, i.e. an item with non-zero proportion (usually just 1), before it. The simplest way to do it is to add a stretchable spacer, i.e. add `SplitSizer.AddStretchSpacer()` before adding the "back" button to the sizer.

Note that this will both push the "back" button to the bottom and the other two buttons to the top. If you want to avoid this, e.g. by centring the other buttons, you know what to do: just add another stretch spacer before them.